# Windows security popup appears behind the main application window

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, windows-security

I am using Windows 10 APIs "Passport" & "Window Hello" in my WPF application.

```
bool keyCredentialAvailable = await KeyCredentialManager.IsSupportedAsync();
if (keyCredentialAvailable)
{
      KeyCredentialRetrievalResult keyCreationResult = await KeyCredentialManager.RequestCreateAsync("Hi", KeyCredentialCreationOption.ReplaceExisting);

}
```

`RequestCreateAsync` method opens the popup which asks for biometric or pin. Which is visible in the screenshot at the back of MainWindow.

I don't have any reference for this Popup that I can bring it in front. Also, I am calling this method on my MainWindow's `Loaded` method so that it can be confirmed that Main window is loaded fully.

**Issue with Popup positioning**
 [image: Issue Right now]

**Expected Positioning**
[image: Expected]

Comment: Can you show the code you are using, i mean, i have never used this api/feature before, but i have no idea how to test it even if i wanted to

Comment: @TheGeneral I have updated the question with code and expected result

Comment: @Heena, did you find the answer since you posted the question? I'm also faced with this issue and searching the solution

Comment: @Heena I'm facing the same problem, although my application accesses the API differently (it's a Java application that uses WinRT/C++ to access KeyCredentialManager). Did you find anything?

Answer (score 1):

I filed a Github issue with Microsoft's C++/WinRT project, which I use to access the same API, and face the problem.

https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/issues/999#issuecomment-897675623

No solution, but "This usually happens when the parent window isn't set correctly."
I have no idea how to set the parent window correctly in this case, as the API does not expose any handles on the popup.

Answer (score 0):

First, check whether your function is async.

```
private async void SignInPassport()
{
 bool keyCredentialAvailable = await KeyCredentialManager.IsSupportedAsync();
 if (keyCredentialAvailable)
 {
  KeyCredentialRetrievalResult keyCreationResult = await KeyCredentialManager.RequestCreateAsync("Hi",KeyCredentialCreationOption.ReplaceExisting);
  }
}
```

if this does not solve your issue try this [microsoft-passport-login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/microsoft-passport-login#exercise-1-login-with-microsoft-passport)

Comment: function is Async  `private async void MainWindow_LoadedAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`

Comment: I have checked the link you shared. It is in UWP and my app is in WPF. When I create a Release build I face this issue. Will I be able to create the build for UWP and verify the same?

Comment: Yes, you can create a build for UWP. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps#sideload-your-app-package